# Blue bar at bottom of screen, then laptop restarts

Tags: windows, windows-vista, crash, reboot

So I've been having an issue with my HP 6735s laptop.

I went on holiday for two weeks, and after I returned (yesterday) and used my laptop, everything was fine when, suddenly, the entire screen went black except for a blue bar across the bottom of the screen. 
The screen stayed like this for perhaps 5-6 seconds, before it restarted (and loaded up normally, with the exception of the "windows did not shut down properly" screen). I was able to use the laptop again without issue.

Then this morning, once again while using Google Chrome to browse the internet, the same thing happened again.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue and stop it from happening?

The laptop runs Windows Vista (32 bit); 4gb ram; 1.9 ghz AMD Athlon X2 dual-core QL-60 processor; and an ATI HD3200 graphics card.

Thanks

Comment: You probably saw an incomplete blue screen of death, which means there is some serious problem with your machine. Was the machine overheat or did it sustain any physical damage recently? Maybe it's some new hardware you installed or system updates?

Comment: The laptop is prone to overheating, and if it runs at 100% cpu load for more than 10 minutes it shuts itself off (probably due to a dusty fan). I have installed some new hardware/programs recently (a webcam), so I'll uninstall those and see if that fixes it. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: The maximum operation temperature of your CPU is 100 degrees Celsius. When your CPU reaches that temperature it will automatically shutdown. However, other components like GPU and memory may not have this kind of thermo-protection and may malfunction if they overheat. You can use tools like Real Temp to monitor your system temperature and if the CPU temperature gets close to 100°C (e.g. over 80), you should try to find someway to cool it down. If it doesn't ever get close to that, the blue screen could be caused by other problem (most likely RAM or graphics card).